# explain how do you get area by subtracting antiderivative of upper limit and antiderivative of lower limit

Tags: calculus

First of all is it true that you get area under the curve if you take upper limit and subtract lower limit from it you get area.

And how is it possible. Anti derivative of function is what. What does it show.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x):\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ be a continuous function.  Let $A(x)$ be the area bounded by $y=0, y=x,x=0,$ and $f(x)$.  Now, consider the area between $y=x$ and $y=x+h$, which is equal to $A(x+h)-A(x)$.  We can bound this area by noting that it must be strictly between $hf(x)$ and $hf(x+h)$ (these are the areas of two rectangles with vertices on the $x$-axis and at $f(x)$ or $f(x+h)$).  WLOG (without loss of generality), let $$hf(x)\le A(x+h)-A(x)\le hf(x+h)$$
Then $$ f(x)\le \frac{A(x+h)-A(x)}{h}\le f(x+h) $$
Taking the limit as $h\to 0$, we see $A'(x)=f(x)$, so the antiderivative is the "area" function.

Answer (score 0):

by taking the antiderivative $\int_{a}^b f(x)dx$ you are summing up the values of $f(x)$ within  a small $dx$ width in the $x$ axis from the given limits $x=a$ to $x=b$. this is nothing but the area of the region between the $f(x)$ and the $x$ axis.